# c# VLC.Dotnet play and then pause issue

Tags: c#, button, vlc.dotnet

I hope someone will be able to help me with my issue. i want to take a screenshot of the video at a specific time index, however when i try to change the time all i get is a blank black screen. i added buttons which play and pause, it allows me to play and pause the video, if i do that and then change the time index, i get an image. im confused as to why it doesn’t work using code. i even preform btnplay.PeformClick(); to play the video and when i do btnpause.PerformClick() to pause the video it doesn’t.

it seems that i can only get an image of the video if i have to physically hit the play and then pause button on my form, im trying to achieve this using code

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           


            ////////////////////LC4 VLC Settings///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            control = new VlcControl();
            var currentAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
            var currentDirectory = new FileInfo(currentAssembly.Location).DirectoryName;
            var libDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "libvlc", IntPtr.Size == 4 ? "win-x86" : "win-x64"));
            control.BeginInit();
            control.VlcLibDirectory = libDirectory;
            control.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            control.EndInit();
            panel1.Controls.Add(control);
            
            main_form_LC4_data();
        }
        
         void main_form_LC4_data()
        {
        long vOut3 = 20;
        playfile("path to file");
        First_Frame(vOut3);
        }
        
          void playfile(string final)
        {
           control.SetMedia(new Uri(final).AbsoluteUri);
            control.Time = 0;
            control.Update();
            
        }
        
         void First_Frame(long vOut3)
        {
            control.Time = vOut3;

        }
        
          private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            control.Play();
            Console.WriteLine("PLAY");
        }

        private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            control.Pause();
            Console.WriteLine("PAUSE");
        }
```

Above is my code in a nut shell

i have tried things like this

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           First_Frame(first_frame); // jump to index
        }
```

and then calling up `button10.PerformClick();` however it doesnt seem to work. once again if i physically hit the buttons on my form it works perfectly, however not in the way of coding it.

as an example :

1. play.PeformClick();
2. Pause.PeformClick();
3. time = vOut3;

I do hope this isnt to confusing im really stuck and am still hoping someone can help me

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

```cs
control.Update();
```

this does nothing.

You need to wait for the `Playing` event to be raised after setting the time, otherwise libvlc doesn't have the time to decode the frame and display it (setting the time is asynchronous)